# $L^1$ and a.s. convergence of $L^1$ of $X_n = 1_{\{U \leq 1/n\}}$ where $U \sim U(0,1)$

Tags: probability-theory

I am trying to study the $L^1$ and a.s. convergence of $L^1$ of $X_n = 1_{\{U \leq 1/n\}}$, where $U \sim U(0,1)$. For the $L^1$ convergence I think I could use that $|X_n| \leq 1$ and use the bounded convergence theorem. How can I show that $X_n \to 0 \ a.s$ though? I think the Borel-Cantelli lemma doesn't apply here.

Comment: $X_n(\omega)\to 0$ for all $\omega$ (almost all $\omega$ if you wish to be pedantic)

Comment: What about the set where $X_n(\omega) = 1$?

Comment: In those points $X_n(\omega) \neq 0$

Comment: Don't focus on $\{\omega : X_n(\omega) \ne 0\}$ for each $n$. Instead focus on the set $\{\omega : X_n(\omega) \not \to 0\}$ and show it has zero measure.

Comment: Is it enough to say that when $n \to +\infty$, then $P(U \leq 1/n) = 1/n \to 0$?

Comment: Are you familiar with the definition of almost sure convergence?

Comment: The definition I am working with is that if $X_n(\omega) \to X(\omega) \ \forall \omega \in \Omega \Rightarrow X_n \to X \ c.s$, where $P(\Omega) =1.$